# How to write code to handle different serialization formats

Tags: c++, serialization

This is my understand of how "good" serialization code should work (and please correct me if I am confused):

- There are serializer and deserializer classes
- These classes are designed to serialize/deserialize different primitive types
- More complex types (e.g., classes) are (eventually) composed of primitive types
- Some function must be written to "decompose" a complex type into primitive types

Thus, a very simple serializer might look like:

```
class Serializer {
public:
    void visit(int v);
    void visit(unsigned int v);
    void visit(float v);
    //Other primitive types
};
```

Then a type like:

```
class Timestamp {
private:
    unsigned int _value;

    template <typename ARCHIVE>
    friend
    void serialize(ARCHIVE& archive, const ComplexType& v);
};
```

Would have a serialization function like:

```
template <typename ARCHIVE>
void serialize(ARCHIVE& archive, const Timestamp & v) {
    archive.visit(v._value);
}
```

I beleive this is similar to what boost serialization does.

This is all fine and dandy except for one problem... In my mind, serialization comes in MANY different forms.  For example:

- Transmitting a type over the network
- Saving a type to a file

  - As JSON
  - As XML
  - As binary data
- Printing the type as a string

This presents a problem because the same type might have VERY different representations (of even its primitive types) depending on the serializer.

In the example above, for example, a timestamp can be stored or transmitted as merely a 4-byte integer value (on a 32-bit system).  However, the string serializer should render the type as something like "2022-07-21 14:42:03.123"

This cannot be achieved with a universal serialize function as I showed above.

My one thought is "template specialization to the rescue!"

```
template <>
void serialize<StringSerializer>(StringSerializer& archive, const Timestamp& v) {
    //I guess convert v._value to a string somehow
}
```

Something still seems amiss with this method though.

What is the correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this through a combination of overloading and template specialization.  For the particular example of timestamps, you can simply overload your `serialize` function for the text serializer and timestamp types.

Alternatively, you could give your serialization back-ends traits, and specialize when the trait says it wants textual output.  Or, you could define a `to_string` method, and in certain back-ends check whether there's a `to_string` method and use that to convert the structure to a string rather than recursing into its individual fields.

Much of this gets a lot easier if you are willing to use C++20, because then you can check for the presence of methods much more easily than SFINAE by using `requires` clauses.  For example:

```
template<typename T> void
serialize(TextSerializer &ts, const T &t)
{
  if constexpr (requires { to_string(t); }) {
    // use to_string(t) to represent serialized object
  }
  else {
    // visit field by field
  }
}
```